# Why a new thread points to main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

First, i have a weak property. It points to the thread that is not main thread.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id weakThread;

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    {
        NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(threadRun) object:nil];
        self.weakThread = thread;
        [thread start];
    }
    NSLog(@"main: %@, %p", self.weakThread, self.weakThread);
    return YES;
}

- (void)threadRun {
    NSLog(@"current: %@, %p", [NSThread currentThread], [NSThread currentThread]);
    NSLog(@"self.weakThread in thread: %@, %p", self.weakThread, self.weakThread);
}
```

Look at these code. After i run, this is output:

```
main: <NSThread: 0x608000278240>{number = 5, name = main}, 0x608000278240
current: <NSThread: 0x608000278240>{number = 5, name = (null)}, 0x608000278240
self.weakThread in thread: <NSThread: 0x608000278240>{number = 5, name = (null)}, 0x608000278240
```

the pointer is never changed. But the thread is changed. I don't know why it is changed to main thread. 
You see the first output, name is main.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `self.weakThread` and `[NSThread currentThread]` in your code are the same, so the pointer doesn't need to be changed. It did not change to the main thread(the name 'main' is fake). You can prove it by assigning a name to thread:

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(threadRun) object:nil];
thread.name = @"a thread";
```

The result will be changed to

```
"{number = 5, name = a thread}".
```

And you will find out that the real main thread has the different address by:

```
NSLog(@"real main: %@", [NSThread mainThread]);
NSLog(@"my thread: %@", self.weakThread);
```